# WebScrape - Find Element by - Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

My code goes into a website, clicks on a drop down and scrapes **only the first entry** of the dropdown.

But I want all entries within the drop down (You can see a visual of this if you run my code)

Ideally, I would do this by find_element using class name, but for me only xpath works, maybe i am doing something wrong.

Any help scraping all entries would be appreciated

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
bracket=[]
driver.get('https://www.eventscribe.net/2021/ASPENePosters/searchbyposterbucket.asp?f=PosterTrack&pfp=BrowsebyPosterBucket')
time.sleep(1)
driver.get('https://www.eventscribe.net/2021/ASPENePosters/searchbyposterbucket.asp?f=PosterTrack&pfp=BrowsebyPosterBucket')
time.sleep(2)


firstDropdown=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bucketPres"]/li[1]/div')
firstDropdown.click()
time.sleep(1)
li=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="bucketPres"]/div[1]/li[1]/a/div') #trying to get all entries
for item in li:
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change /li[1] to //li to get all lis.

```
li=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="bucketPres"]/div[1]//li/a/div')
```

You could also do this instead.

```
values=[item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="bucketPres"]/div[1]//li/a/div')] #trying to get all entries
print(values)
```

Outputs

```
P86 - Enteral Feeding Volumes: Can You Trust Your Numbers? A Pilot Study Optimizing Accuracy of Documentation in the Hospital Setting
P87 - Cost-effectiveness Comparison of High Protein Enteral Feedings Used in the ICU: Retrospective Adjusted Analysis
P88 - Predictability of nitrogen balance for critically ill patients with severe traumatic injuries
P89 - Vitamin D Deficiency Among Adult Lung and Liver Transplant Patients: A Retrospective Review
P90 - Calorie Deficit Calculator to Facilitate Adequate Nutrition in the Trauma ICU
P91 - The effect of oxandrolone on weight loss and muscle mass in acute spinal cord injury patients
P92 - Application of preoperative fasting abbreviation protocol in patients subject to femur fracture surgery
P93 - Reduction of hypercalcemia following readjustment of target serum 25-hydroxy vitamin D concentration during cholecalciferol therapy in vitamin D deficient, critically ill patients
P94 - Gastric Feeding Intolerance in Critically Ill Patients During Sustained Pharmacologic Neuromuscular Blockade
P95 - Beneficial effects of a long-acting GLP-2 analog, HM15912, after switching from daily or weekly GLP-2 analog drugs in animal models
P96 - Utilization of Indirect Calorimetry for Calculation of Nutritional Goals and its Effect in Ventilator-free days and Muscle Thickness in Septic Mechanically Ventilated Patients
P97 - Pilot Quality Improvement Study: Exploring PEG Placements in Critically Ill COVID-19 Patients
P99 - Adequacy and complications of enteral nutritional therapy in critically ill patients with COVID-19
P100 - Challenges in Parenteral Nutrition in Adult Ultra-Short Gut: A Case of Cachexia
P101 - Retrospective Examination of Copper Supplementation in Burn Patients
P102 - Utilization of Peptide Based Diets in Severely Ill Patients
P103 - Association of Nutritional Delivery on Skeletal Muscle Wasting and Inflammation in Critically Ill Adult Patients: A Systematic Review
P98 - Impact of Vasoactive Medication on Enteral Nutrition in Pediatric Acute Respiratory Distress Syndrome
P104 - The Effect of Preoperative Non NPO Feeding Protocol on Nutrition Delivery and Pneumonia Incidence in Critically-Ill Trauma Patients
P105 - The impact of a carbohydrate loading drink on postprandial glycemic responses and gastric emptying in adults with prediabetes and type 2 diabetes mellitus
P106 - Increasing Hypermetabolism during Hospitalization in COVID-19 Patients Undetected by Common Predictive Energy Equations
P107 - Respiratory Quotient as a Predictor of Clinical Outcomes in Intubated, Critically Ill COVID-19 Patients
P108 - Micronutrient INTake from Enteral nutrition in critically ill adult patients expressed as a percentage of the Australia and New Zealand Nutrient Reference Values: a retrospective observational study.
P109 - The effect of intermittent or continuous feeding and amino acid concentration on urea-to-creatinine ratio in critical illness
P110 - NUTRIC Scores in Trauma Patients: A Comparison of Energy and Protein Needs
```